# Is it possible to get data from hdfs using http protocol (instead of hdfs://)?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm able to get data from hdfs using the following uri: `hdfs://HOST:PORT/DATA_PATH.`
Is there an option to change to protocol of the url from hdfs to http?
for example: `http://GOST:PORT/DATA_PATH`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to configure WebHDFS rest access. See [WebHDFS – HTTP REST Access to HDFS](http://hortonworks.com/blog/webhdfs-%E2%80%93-http-rest-access-to-hdfs/).